Etymology of nigh/near/next
The word "near" started as a comparative of "nigh":

nigh -> near -> next

from Old English:

neah -> nearra -> nehsta

at one point in the development of the English language "next" was reinterpreted as base form and "nigh" was replaced:

near -> nearer -> nearest

Can someone help with a historical perspective on when this switch took place? I have not used Google ngram or similar services because their scientific value is quite limited, on the other hand I am not an expert in Anglistics and lack the knowledge of reputable sources. So, if someone could, as a bonus, suggest literature I'd be indebted.
(For reference: for German there is "the Kluge": Kluge/Seebold, Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache. Is there something similar for English?)

You really need to obtain access to the OED. The etymology and development of near/nigh/next are laid out in great detail in all their spellings and (for the most part) pronunciations. You also might like to consider the Modern German "nächst" (nearest) and "next".

@Greybeard: reserching "nächst" and "nahe/näher/nahest(nächst,nähest)" and their etymology was actually exactly what brought on this question.

Etymonline shows that the differentiation between nigh and near was gradual and took place before the 14th century. This is what it says in the entry for nigh:

The Old English progression was neah - near - niehsta, for "nigh - nigher - nighest." But the comparative near and the superlative nehst gradually evolved into separate words that were no longer felt as related to nigh. New comparative and superlative forms nigher, nighest developed 14c. as phonetic changes obscured the original relationships.

The entry for near gives a more specific timeframe:

Old English near "closer, nearer," comparative of neah, neh "nigh." Partially by the influence of Old Norse naer "near," it came to be used in English as a positive form mid-13c., and new comparative "nearer" developed in the 1500s.

So this change occurred over two centuries.
Not easy to find quotes from that period, but this Middle English Dictionary has plenty in the original form of the writings, not rendered into modern day English. It gives the centuries they were written, so this may help you figure out the signs of this change over time.
Note that the spelling of the word near greatly varied:

nẹ̄r adv.(2) Also nēr, nere, nerre, nier, nir, (N) nar(e, narre, (chiefly N) neir, neare, (SWM) neor, (in surn. only) neiare & (error) nerþere.


Great answer! Many thanks for including the links.
